# Where does the tritium on the Earth come from?

Tags: radioactivity, isotopes

As tritium has smaller lifetime than the life of the Universe, it should have decayed before the present age completely. How can the presence of natural tritium be explained in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tritium#Cosmic_rays) says that the half-life of tritium is 12.32 years, but that naturally produced tritium on Earth is the result of cosmic rays interacting with atmospheric gases.

> > Tritium occurs naturally due to cosmic rays interacting with atmospheric gases. In the most important reaction for natural production, a fast neutron (which must have energy greater than 4.0 MeV) interacts with atmospheric nitrogen.

Comment: So, cosmic rays (charged particles lke protons) with atmospheric hydrogen and helium  form tritium. That's what you mean, right?

Comment: Hi @AaronJohnSabu.  I don't know any more than I wrote.  I answered your question with a quick Google search.  If you follow the link in my answer, you will see a nuclear reaction diagram with inputs and outputs.  The quote in my answer says that nitrogen is involved.